# python interpreter and vscode in mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pythoninterpreter

I am having 2 problems.

I am working on a remote server with vscode. When I use the command `code` to launch the vscode, it only launches it when I am not connected to the server. I searched for solutions online most of them are for windows and not mac, I could not find an answer that solves my problem.

problem2: how can I download a specific python interpreter in vscode.

I used this code to create a virtual environment:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3env
```

but it does not allow me to specify the version of the python interpreter.

Comment: You can use Remote-SSH

Comment: you don't install the Python interpreter IN VSC, you do this in the OS/Terminal. Use `full-python-exe-path.exe -m venv env-name` to specify the Python version to use for the virt env

Comment: Vsc supports running locally but connected to a remote server. I strongly encourage you to check it out rather than attempting to launch vsc on the remote

Comment: you don't have VSC installed on the remote, start VSC locally and connect to the server with the remote-ssh extension, read the VSC Remote doc pages

Comment: can I have more information about how to use full-python-exe-path.exe -m venv env-name, if I want to download python7.3 ... for the connection with remote server I have no issues but my issue is that if I use the command code it does not launch vscode when connecting to the server. It only launches it when not connecting to the server

Answer (score 0):

You could install the `Remote-SSH` extension for VSCode, it will allow you to connect to a remote server and have access to its files, you can install Remote-SSH from the VSCode MarketPlace

For the second problem first download the version of python you want here https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/, then just do `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.7 py3env` it will use `python 3.7` in a virtual environment, for another version just replace `python 3.7` in the command by the path of the appropriate python executable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a specific way of downloading python in the terminal? I have successfully connected to the server

Comment: yes, you can do curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.0/Python-3.10.0.tgz --output Python-3.10.0.tgz, or better if you have a package manager like Homebrew, then you can do brew install python@3.10